# Complete Ingredient List/Database?

Tags: ingredients

I'm looking for an extensive database of grains, hops, yeasts, and other additives. Preferably with information like potential, SRM, alpha, flocculation, etc.

I've found BeerSmith's lists, but the copyright is questionable, and the data isn't exhaustive.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [Hopville.com](http://hopville.com). Their recipe creator, which is free, lists a lot of info on malts/hops/yeasts etc. You can even add new ingredients as they come out and enter their info as well.

Comment: Wow, that's an extensive dataset. I'm building an application (similar to Hopville) and need some raw data, some sort of table format.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I know why you're looking...

To get the full line of data you want, without the copyright issues, you might want to start with a manufacturer list from BeerSmith or any of the other ones, and then grab the manufacturer catalogs. You might even be able to find them online (ie scrape-able).

[Brewers Supply Group](http://www.brewerssupplygroup.com/index.html) has a LOT of their info online, save for pricing. Check out their [malt](http://www.brewerssupplygroup.com/Malt.html), for example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the links. I have also found the list at homebrewtalk.com's wiki to be useful, especially this chart: http://homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Malts_Chart.

It's the closest thing to what I'm looking for, but a true dataset (SQL, XML, or other format would be better).

I'll keep looking and update this answer as I find more.

Comment: Opensource data set go!